# Show local system info (Username, local IP...) in dialog on Windows OS natively

Tags: windows, dialog, native

I want to write a very simple application that could run nativey on Windows (or script or whatever is more efficient) that shows a dialog with this information:

- Local IP
- Public IP
- User name
- PC name
- Domain name

I have a little experience in programming (mainly in Java and VBA) and I managed to write a Java program to do this, the problem is that the user needs the JRE in his machine to run it and not every user has it. I have seen options about bundling the JRE with the java application but that'd also require the user to unzip the JRE before running the program.

I've been reading and watching tutorials on C and C++, but before I dive into writing an actual application for such a simple task, I was wondering if there wasn't a simpler way to accomplish it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Windows batch script should be able to do it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation(v=vs.110).aspx